# Exchange Server: All a user's items are being moved to Junk Mail

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook

I have a user who is somehow having all messages sent to his junk mail folder, and I'm posting this to see if there is a server side setting I should check

This is an Exchange 2010 SP3 environment with no Edge servers.  The following transport settings are configured:

- `Set-ContentFilterConfig -Enabled:$false`

Mailbox settings:

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>Get-MailboxJunkEmailConfiguration jgoodman

Enabled                  : False
TrustedListsOnly         : False
ContactsTrusted          : False
TrustedSendersAndDomains : {}
BlockedSendersAndDomains : {}
MailboxOwnerId           : company.com/Enterprise/Users/Goodman, j
Identity                 : company.com/Enterprise/Users/Goodman, j
IsValid                  : True
```

There are no transport rules (or transport agents) that are installed or enabled that would do this.

```
 [PS] C:\Windows\system32>Get-TransportAgent
Identity                                           Enabled         Priority
--------                                           -------         --------
Transport Rule Agent                               True            1
Text Messaging Routing Agent                       True            2
Text Messaging Delivery Agent                      True            3
```

- OWA message rules are empty
- Junk mail safe senders are empty (in Outlook UI)

Does anyone know of any other reason messages would move to the junk folder, or how I can diagnose what is causing this to occur?

Comment: Based on what you showed, the only thing that would be affecting it should be client side.  If their Outlook is closed and you send them an email from Gmail or similar does it stay in their OWA Inbox until they open Outlook or does it still go to the junk mail folder in OWA?

Comment: @TheCleaner When Outlook is closed, the message moves to Junk in about 15 to 30 seconds.  We asked the user to change their password in case it's an app on a phone, or other device that is moving the messages.

Comment: Yep I'm betting a mobile app then

Answer (score 2):

[The junk mail folder in Outlook is purely client-side anyway](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179183%28v=office.15%29.aspx), so that's where you have to look for your problem.

First, I'd try a new Outlook profile, second I'd reinstall Outlook and third, I'd [just disable the junk mail folder](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/change-the-level-of-protection-in-the-junk-email-filter-HP010356454.aspx).  If the user doesn't have a problem with just disabling the junk mail filter, that's the first thing I'd do - it causes more problems than it solves anyway.